# Shell Script: Unable to replace regex matched group in yml file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I referred multiple answers but none of them is helping in my problem, therefore raised a new question.
Here are the details:

```
echo $testPorts
output:    - "4441:4441" - "5905:5900"
```

- Now I need to replace the ports available in test.yml file with above
- output in the same format as per test.yml.

  `Regex: (ports:)(\n.*\n.*)`
- Need to replace the 2nd group with above ports in test.yml and my
- **expected yml will be**

```
    version: '2'
    services:
        ports:
          - "4441:4441"
          - "5905:5900"
```

I have spent so much time on this still unable to figure out the solution.

Commands that I have tried:(they all didn't work)

```
sed -E 's/(ports:)(\n.*\n.*)/\2 ${'testPorts'}/g' test.yml

sed -E 's/(ports:)(\n.*\n.*)/\2 $'testPorts'/g' test.yml
```

`sed -r` is also not working.

**Original test.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "5901:5900"
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo "$testPorts"`. Sed parses _one line_ at a time, to read next line in sed, use `n` or `N` command in sed. Do you expect `ports` to have only ever two lines after it that need replacing or the number of lines can differ?

Comment: @KamilCuk, output is "4441:4441" - "5905:5900"
Number of lines will remain 2 only it will not differ.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant info in the post. Newlines are not visible in comments. Sed has commands terminated by newlines. If your `testPorts` variable contains newlines, another method needs to be used. Probably it does, but your `echo $testPorts` doesn't say much, because it's not quoted. Please include the relevant information in the question.

Comment: Your quoting is wrong. You need to quote this way: `'s/(ports:)(\n.*\n.*)/\2 '"${testPorts}"'/g'`

Comment: @ceving, it gives sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Because `testPorts` contains a newline, so sed sees `s/..../<newline>` and terminates with unterminated `s` command, as the third `/` is missing..

Comment: @ceving, could you please help me on how to fix this. or any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The following code just waits for `ports:` line, then ignores the next two lines and in place of them prints the content of `testPorts` variable. I am assuming, that the `testPorts` variable contains the proper number of tabs or newlines in front of the content on each line.

The following saves the content of `testPorts` variable to some file without a trailing newline. Then `sed` waits for a line containing `ports:`. If the line contains ports, it is printed, next two lines are appended to pattern space and removed. Then the content of the temporary file is appended to the output. Because `echo` outputs a newline and I got some problems in the output, I also read the next line after adding the ports and remove the extra newline.

```
echo "$testPorts" > tempfile.txt
sed '/ports:/{ p;N;N;s/.*//; r tempfile.txt'$'\n'' N; s/\n//; }' input.txt
```

The newline after `r` command in `sed` is needed, as commands in `sed` are separated by newlines (the `;` "command" will be parsed as part of the filename). More about `sed` scripting can be learnt from [this introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). The `$'\n'` is a newline - it uses [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

You *could* do it like you wanted - ie. match two newlines after encountering `ports:`. For that you have to substitute newlines in `testPorts` variable for two characters - `\` and `n`. Then you can use that variable in GNU sed with `-z` option to parse the whole file. Because regexes are greedy, you have to explicitly define the regex to match up until a space to match a line. The `<<<` is a bash extension the [here string](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings). I could write a script in posix-ish sed to match the lines and replace them, but I feel that is not worth the effort here.

```
testports_escaped=$(sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' <<<"$testPorts")
sed -z 's/\([[:space:]]*ports:[^\n]*\n\)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n/\1'"$testports_escaped"'/' input.txt
```

But because the operation is just removing two lines after `ports:`, I would just do this, with looks the most verbose:

```
{
    sed '/ports:/q'
    read
    read
    printf "%s\n" "$testPorts"
    cat
} < input.txt
```

My attempt at doing this in awk would look like this:

```
awk -v v="$testPorts" '/ports:/{ print; getline; getline; print v; getline; }1' input.txt
```

I tried to test these snippets [in repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/InsubstantialIllList). Note that modifying structured text formats like yaml using regex is not advised - it's better to use yaml syntax "aware" tools for that.

Ps. You could use the regex `ports:.*\n.*\n.*` (without the trailing `\n`) in more posix-sh sed, by buffering 3 lines in the pattern buffer and printing only one line at a time with hold space shuffeling, but I find it not worth the effort here:

```
sed -n 'N;N;
  : a; {
    /ports:.*\n.*\n.*/{
            s/.*/ports:/
            r tempfile.txt'$'\n''
            b end
        }
        $ b end
        h
        s/\n.*//
        p
        g
        s/[^\n]*\n//
        N
    }; b a
    : end ; {
        : all
            p
            $ q
            n
        b all
    }
' input.txt
```

Comment: I tried 
`{   sed '/container_name:/q'  printf "$testPorts" >>docker-compose.yml } < docker-compose.yml`
test.yml is edited and output is below which gives me syntax error in yml file.I want ports and its keys as a list for container_name
 `version: '2'
 services:
  container_name: test11
   ports:
  - "4441:4441"
  - "5905:5900" `
My expected file should be in below format:

`version: '2'
services:
   container_name: test11
      ports:
        - "4441:4441"
        - "5905:5900" `

Also i was unable to find that what is the use of /q  in  sed '/container_name:/q'

Comment: And? Is there a question? [sed introduction, chapter about 'q'](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-34)  I even posted a link to repl with examples - study it.